# Google Play Store showing Open button instead of Update button

Tags: android, google-play

I updated my app to the Google Play Store last night. 
Before the update, my App version was 2.3.
There was some problem in version 2.4 so after another 2-3 hour, I updated the app again.
The current version on the play store is 2.5.

My Problem is: If the old version is installed on the device and open play store Google Play Store showing **open button** instead of **Update button**. I want **update button**. What is the problem? Any solution?

Comment: this happen when the app build version is same as of the the app store build version.

Comment: Already changed version of new apk.

Comment: still it shows same "open" button

Comment: Yes, I tried to search for this and read somewhere , It will take 24 hr for update on Play store. so I will wait for 24 hr.

Comment: yes offcourse, there is a little *Exclamation* mark next to your app name if it is still in propagation. If it isn't it means it is propagated.

Comment: @chirag i face same issue please help me if you found solution

Comment: @Android User It will display automatically after some hours.

Comment: Or You need to clear catch of Google Playstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following use cases that you can try.

1. It will update button after some time, so wait for some time
2. Mostly it is a catch issue. So try to open/close the app several times. (Worked in my case)
3. At the current time(Aprin-May 2020) it is taking almost 4-5 days to publish app due to COVID-19. I checked in play console, the status is "Your app is published" but I see an actual update after 2 days.

Answer (score 50):

In order to show an update in Google Play, your app either should have been installed through Google Play or it should be a system application.

If you have installed your application through adb or installed from other sources, Google play will show "Open" instead of "Update".

Comment: Yes you are right. In my case I installed app from Playstore. It displayed automatically after some hours.

Comment: Useful Info in my case

Comment: I also have this problem and I need Play Store to show the button update rather than open, as my app is installed on many customers phones already. Do you know technically why "update" is not showing and do you have any reference to some official documentation?

Comment: @Sinapse , I have the same issue.
most users won't need this though since the app auto-updates while they're sleeping, they won't even know it updated. My issue is for user that have auto-update turned off.
I built in to the app a dialog that pops up if their version is lower than the current version, and sends them to google play to update.
With this bug, they go in circles. app to play to app to play....
If this is a prob on the users' end (need to Clear cache for Google Play Services)
I need to know if there's a way to get their services in order for them.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that there is a "glitch" with the update button in that it desappears in landscape mode, and is only visible in portrait mode. When I searched to find out what this was about, I came across this page (we are on), so I thought I'd post my answer here for anyone who might also be stumped and might stumble here.

Comment: In my case, Update button will appear after some hours. So wait for some time. If update button not show after some time then got for other solution.

Comment: @user6170930 "this link" means this very page we are on, not another page somewhere else. I have updated to reflect this. if you mean I should post that link, would do but it was just one of many fruitless google searches and it was way down in the search results. I tried to recreate it but no go...

Comment: Wow... 5 years later, this bug still exists. In 2021, on Android 11, I had to rotate to Landscape mode to get the Update button to appear instead of the Open button! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As earlier answered suggested first its need to check there must be app is signed or downloaded from play store.

If it is download from play store even its not showing update button then follow below steps

1. Ensure you're connected to a Wi-Fi or mobile data network.
2. Clear cache for Google Play Services app (Go to Settings > Apps or Application Manager > ALL > Google Play Services > Clear cache > OK).
3. Clear cache data for the Google Play Store app.
4. Uninstall and reinstall the Play Store updates. (Go to Settings > Apps or Application Manager > Google Play Store app > Uninstall Updates > OK). As long as you have a strong Internet connection (Wi-Fi or mobile data), your Play Store app will update to the latest version within a few minutes.
5. Install system updates. To do this, try the steps listed below:
   Open your device's main Settings app.
   Select About or System updates (depending on your device, this may be different).
   If an update is available, follow the on-screen instructions to install it on your device.
   Now, please check if the update button is available.
6. Restart your device.

Also, you can check update available or not from Side Menu->My Apps and Game->Update Tab. here you can see all apps which have new updates

Answer (score 2):

I've found that even when there is no update button on the product page in the app store, there will be an update button in search results.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the update button shown after I restarted the phone or restarted the playstore

Answer (score 0):

Go to **"Settings"** within android device then on one of the tabs selections it should say **"All"** press that then look for the **"Google play store"**.

Once you press that you can check what version play store your phone is currently running to make sure if it's running version 2.3 or 2.5.