# when i update an new version Google Play Store showing Open button instead of Update button

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I updated my app to the Google Play Store 4th aug last night. Before the update, my App version was 1.0.0.1 There was some problem in version 1.0.0.1  I updated version 1.0.0.1 to 1.0.0.2.
The current version on the play store is 1.0.0.2.

[image]

My Problem is: If the old version is installed on the device and open play store Google Play Store showing open button instead of Update button. I want update button. What is the problem? Any solution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Store showing Open button instead of Update button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086791/google-play-store-showing-open-button-instead-of-update-button) Specifically, **check again in 24 hours**, see if the button changes as it should. Also, **power off the phone**. Power it back on. If that fixes it, then I think most customers will see the correct button. I suspect Play Store app is caching some info.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have debug apk installed on phone. To update apk you need to have same app with the same package name and same signed apk.

> try uninstalling current apk to installed new apk

Comment: No i am not using debug apk bro. yes, i have same app with same package and same signed apk .Apk uninstall and install working fine . I need Play Store to show the button update rather than open, as my app is installed on many customers phones already. Do you know technically why "update" is not showing and do you have any reference to some official documentation. Customers don't do the uninstall operation.

Comment: there can be multiple reasons like you have installed beta version then update option not showing

Answer (score 0):

If you restart Google Play on your device, the button Update will appear. But only if the update is approved.